# How to power down display on terminal?

Tags: linux, console, screen-lock

I would like to power down/up my display from the terminal.

Right now I have:

```
setterm --blank force
#wake
setterm --blank poke
```

Which gives a blank screen; but active screen (screen still receives output from computer, just blank output, it won't enter a "no signal" state)

How would I turn off the display completely like you can do from X with this?

```
xset dpms force off
#wake
xset dpms force on
```

Answer (score 2):

Blank screen after 1 min and turn it off after 2 min. Any keypress will turn it back on:

```
setterm --blank 1 --powerdown 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing:

```
sudo sh -c 'vbetool dpms off; read ans; vbetool dpms on'
```

As [the following thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62858/turn-off-monitor-using-command-line) suggests.

Comment: This seems like it would work... but for me I always just get an illegal instruction error. I'm gonna see what happens if I install the cpu microcodes though... although I'd kinda rather avoid those. Edit: Nope, microcodes did not fix this, so I cannot use this method, guessing it has something to do with arch-linux.

Comment: Are you sure you have the `vbetool` installed? https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/vbetool/

Comment: Duh, otherwise it would be command not found. Illegal Instruction typically means that the action requires an instruction set (like AVX or SSE) that your CPU doesn't support, since this is interfacing with the graphics, might maybe be GPU (idk, I have an i7-2600 sandy bridge and a gtx 550-Ti on proprietary drivers, I would think this should be supported unless the nvidia drivers don't support it)

Comment: It makes sense in a way :), can you please also take a look at this? https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Display_Power_Management_Signaling

Comment: Not really any new information there, I looked at it before I wrote my question. I woulda thought powerdown is the feature I need, but it only offers setting a timer for powerdown, not to just simply power down now.